# Simple Integer Enum

Tags: java, enums

I'm new with `enums` and I'd like to create one to compare an integer to a more comprehensible definition.

```
if (getFruit() == myEnum.APPLE) {
    // ...
}
```

instead of

```
if (getFruit() == 1) {
    // ...
}
```

Where `getFruit()` returns values like `1`,`2` and so on

Comment: The *real* solution is, of course, to make `getFruit` return a `myEnum`.

Comment: so if I make `getFruit()` return an enum, how can I refer to the enum using an integer index? `return fruit.getValue(i)` or something similar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing the point of enums... you use them *instead of* "old school" `int` constants.

Have a look at this:

```
public enum Fruit {
    APPLE,
    ORANGE,
    BANANA
}

public class Dessert {

    private Fruit fruit;

    public Dessert(Fruit fruit) {
        this.fruit = fruit;
    }

    public Fruit getFruit() {
        return fruit;
    }
}

public class Test {

    Dessert dessert = new Dessert(Fruit.APPLE);
    if (dessert.getFruit() == Fruit.ORANGE) {
        // nope
    } else if (dessert.getFruit() == Fruit.APPLE) {
        // yep
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, now I'm a bit less confused V:

Answer (score 4):

You can use `getFruit() == myEnum.APPLE.ordinal()` where ordinal is the order you declare the enums in your file.

```
public enum myEnum {
     APPLE, ORANGE, BANANA;
}
```

The ordinal for APPLE in this case is 0, ORANGE is 1, BANANA is 2.

Or you could do the following:

```
public enum myEnum {
    APPLE(1), ORANGE(2), BANANA(3);

    private final int i;

    private myEnum(int i){
        this.i=i;
    }

    public int getNumber(){
        return i;
    }
}
```

However, I would just make `getFruit()` return an enum.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an enum like this

```
public enum myEnum {
    APPLE  (1),
    ORANGE (2);
}
```

You can also check this [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: In this example, you should include the constructor. Otherwise, a copypasta resulting in incorrect code may confuse OP and others who don't understand the intricacies of using an `enum`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public enum Fruit {
    APPLE  ("apple"), ORANGE ("orange");

    private String value;

    private Fruit(int v) { value = v; }
}
```

getFruit must return Fruit enum

```
public Fruit getFruit() {
    return aFruit;
}
```

Now you can use

```
if (getFruit() == Fruit.APPLE) { //and so on
    // ...
}
```

And if you use enum, its better to use switch-case

```
switch(getFruit()) {
    case Fruit.APPLE: ... break;
    case Fruit.ORANGE: ... break;
}
```